# Let $f:Y\to X$ be the proper birational morphism, prove $H^0(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y(D)) \subset H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X(f_*(D)))$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $f:Y\to X$ be the proper birational morphism between smmoth projective variety, $D$ be an (effective) divisor, prove $H^0(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y(D)) \subset H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X(f_*(D)))$.

---

I saw this statement in Kollar and Mori Lemma 3.40 using this result. I am not sure if this statement is a consequence of some exact sequence? Or can we use something projection formula to deduce it? Sorry I don't have good idea to handle the push foward of divisor？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, under this assumption $H^0(Y, f^*\mathcal{L}) = H^0(X, \mathcal{L})$, for any invertible sheaf $\mathcal{L}$ on $X$. To prove this, we note that the projection formula along with $f_*\mathcal{O}_Y = \mathcal{O}_X$ implies that $f_*f^* \mathcal{L} \cong \mathcal{L}$, so taking global sections yields the required equality. (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1090210/birational-proper-morphism-and-global-sections) for some details)

Now, since $f^*f_*D = D + \sum a_i E_i$ where $E_i$ are exceptional (in particular effective) and $a_i \geq 0$, we see that

$$H^0(Y, \mathcal{O}(D)) \subset H^0(Y, \mathcal{O}(f^*f_*D)) = H^0(X, \mathcal{O}(f_*D))$$ as required.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I learn a lot from this solution.